# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2, php, error

**I am getting this error no product category page**

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element
>   'referenceContainer': This element is not expected. Expected is one of
>   ( action, arguments, block, container, referenceBlock, uiComponent ).
>   Line: 684
>
> Exception  0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'referenceContainer': This element is not expected. Expected
>   is one of ( action, arguments, block, container, referenceBlock,
>   uiComponent ). Line: 684

Answer (score 1):

Please check the latest xml layout changes you made for the catalog category page. You declared a referenceContainer inside a node that seems is not expected.

Comment: I have downloaded the project from the live server without vendor folder and in my local then I run composer install to add dependencies in my local, I don't know where is the problem I am new to Magento.